# Ability to set default sort option for iOS app option lists

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

I'm a big fan of the new app, but I often find myself changing the sort options for selection list. I think it would be useful to provide the user the ability to set the default sorting method for each list. For example: when I tab Tabs, I'd like my Favorites to come up, instead of Popular; and when I click on a particular tab, say MATLAB, I want Newest to display, instead of Votes. It would be great if we could long-tap to set the default, but anything would work. This would really improve my satisfaction with the app. Is there any chance we could get this feature?

Comment: Pretty sure it's a dupe, but I can't find it right now on my phone. +1 I really hate how many steps are required to see newest questions from a favorite tag

Comment: I assumed it would be, but I couldn't find it either. We'll see!

Comment: I don't think the right way to do it is long-tap to set default. It should simply remember your last choice

Comment: Oh, that's a good idea. I don't care, really, I just want the option.